# is it possible to run ubuntu kernel on fedora root filesystem?

Tags: boot, kernel, fedora

My concern is theoretical possibility of running ubuntu kernel with fedora root filesystem (e.g. 3.2.58 ubuntu kernel on fedora 22). It's long story why I need this..
Also, I have no chance to make such experiment on my own.

Is there any critical incompatibility between fedora init/libc and ubuntu kernel?
Maybe someone has an experience like this?

Comment: You probably can, but you woudl lilkely need to build the source into RPM format. If you need a new kernel on Fedora, you may be able to use a old version from a old version of fedora ([probably 16 or 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Fedora_releases#Version_history)). Why do you need the old kernel version (modules can usually be rebuilt for new kernels).

Comment: Interesting experiment. I will follow this. Please keep us posted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably.

Put the kernel into `/boot/vmlinuz-<version>`, put the modules into `/lib/modules/<version>`, run `dracut /boot/initramfs-<version>.img <version>` to generate the initramfs image, cross your fingers, and reboot.

You say, "Also, I have no chance to make such experiment on my own", but of course you do.  Boot up a Fedora VM, put the Ubuntu kernel in place as described here, and see what happens.

There *may* be incompatibilities between some of the user space tools and the kernel, but you should probably be able to boot successfully.